# How can I convert a 2-D cell array to a 3-D cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Each cell is a single element (I'm not storing arrays larger than 1x1 in a cell array... I'm using a cell array to hold both numbers and characters).

The cell array is 32x3822x1 and stores information about amino acid mutations at different positions. Each column represents a different mutation and each row is a different mutation. I want to add a third dimension to indicate the frequency of each mutation. How do I add an additional dimension?

Initializing the cell array as a 3-d one is not an option because importing an excel sheet as a cell array creates a 2-d cell array.

Comment: If `C` is your cell array, then `C{1,1,10}=[]` will assign  an empty array to that index, expanding the array as needed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks. I forgot that they automatically expand, probably bc I try to initialize the size of them up front